# GWT Module Design

Tags: gwt

I have an app with two components.
A customer facing one for submitting restaurant orders.
A vendor facing one for viewing restaurant orders.

Should I have two modules with different entry points as there is no shared code(except for the domain model objects) between the components?

Comment: I think single entry will be fine. If I was at your place may be worked it out like -  providing security 'password' for vendor to check the order, and all customer can place order with out seeing others orders.

Comment: Is Order pojo not common between vendor and customer??

Comment: Actually you are right...there is some common model code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My choice of design(**Using [MVP](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture)**):

1)Single module

2)Same login page (User pojo must have type i.e `vendor` or `customer`).

3)In `OnmoduleLoad` based upon type I'l open Corresponding `vendor or customer presenter`

Why??

1)Code re-usability.

2)Reducing maintenance of 2 modules.

*Well,i am also waiting to see more design options.*

[Please refer](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/02/22/structuring-gwt-modules-for-large-applications/)

Comment: Why can't you re-use code between the two modules? Code reuse doesnt seem a problem to me.

Comment: @DD. That point related to separate login pages for vendor and supplier(*if your are going to design like that*).

Answer (score 0):

There is one reason I can think of for why you may want to do this - which is to reduce download size, since some screens/logic may not be used by the customer (and you want the customer pages to load as fast as possible).  However you can also achieve this with code splitting:  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting

I think having two modules is fine as well.  No big deal there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to deploy them on two separate nodes, I would go with one module. Because you have to maintain only one I18n files, less static files (html), there will be just one module descriptor (no duplication).

If you decide to use just one module, the code splitting is a good thing to consider to reduce the size of JS user have to download.

Answer (score 0):

There can't be 100% correct answer, it really depends on your project.

Separation into two compiled modules might be good idea, in case when the size of your common logic, which has to be shared between two modules is quite small compared to customer/vendor specific logic and most of the time you are writing code only for customer/vendor. In such case you will get faster refresh time in development mode and faster compilation of individual modules to the case when everything is merged together. 
But there is catch, at some point of time, there might be a requirement to create merged customer/vendor mode, because there are users who are customers and vendors at the same time.

I personally prefer approach, when different logical parts of application get their own gwt module, and then there is a root module which links all of them together, plus you have couple of DevOnly modules, which allow you to start only some specific part of application. Example module structure:

- *Customer* module - not compiled separately, depends on Common module
- *Vendor* module - not compiled separately,depends on Common module
- *Common* module - not compiled separately
- **App** module - compiled separately, depends on Customer and Vendor modules
- **VendorStandalone** module - compiled separately, depends on Vendor module, used only for
  development
- **CustomerStandalone** module - compiled separately, depends on Customer module, used only for development

Such structure allows you to have fast developing mode ( if possible at all), and at the same time you prepared for case when Vendor & Customer functionality have to be provided together.